# "Invalid Table Rates File Format" when uploading a Table Rate for "Price vs Destination" for the UK only

Tags: magento

I'm trying to set up delivery charges for a Magento site I'm in charge for. I've been tasked with setting up the shipping charges along the following lines:

```
Basket Cost       |  Delivery Cost
-----------------------------------
£0.00 to £9.99    |  £1
£10.01 to £29.99  |  £2
£30.00 and above  |  £3
```

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping) and I've got up to the point of uploading the CSV file. I've attached a screenshot of the CSV file. [image]

Every time I upload this file though and save it, I get the following error:

> "Invalid Table Rates File Format"

I've based my CSV file on the tutorial, and have tried everything from typing "United Kingdom", "GBR", and "GB", but it still doesn't work. I've also set it as "Price vs Destination" and it's set to just be applicable to the UK only. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Magento doesn't like CSV files that have been edited in a spreadsheet. I had tried both LibreOffice and Excel, both of which caused this issue.

However, when I edited the file in a text editor and uploaded it, it worked straight away. I did try messing about with the save settings in Excel to achieve what the text editor was doing, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggest its not about table values but about file format.

Is your file comma separated or Tab separated.

Just open your file in edit plus or some simple editor.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping link has some explanation.
Here you will find an export button export file using this button and then populate this file and upload.

Answer (score 0):

There is no delivery price for exactly £10. Also I think £0.00 isn't a price. Row 2 column d maybe should be 0.1 you know? 0 isn't a price.

Comment: In the tutorial it uses 0 as a Subtotal value, but I'll check this now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was driving me bonkers.I finally saved the file as Unicode(utf-8) and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

just export using open office but when saving select

1-
[image]

2-

[image]

3- here replace this " with this '

[image]

Answer (score -2):

easy check this https://www.elgentos.nl/tablerates/
creator - easy to use and works perfect